# error image labeling after training

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm trying to retrain the last layer of inception model to recognize my own classes which are images of ornaments form two different styles. I'm getting high accuracy results during training, high validation value, and low cross entropy.  However, the final accuracy is:

`Final test accuracy = 100.0%
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 2 variables.
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 2 variables.
Converted 2 variables to const ops.`

I used the arguments:

> python retrain_new.py --bottleneck_dir=
>   --how_many_training_steps 2000 
>   --model_dir=
>   --output_graph= 
>   --image_dir=
>   --summaries_dir=
>   --output_labels=

The problem is after training is completed when I run the labeling script on an image file to test, I get predictions results using the labels from flowers tutorial and not my new labels (Islamic, baroque) which are included in a generated labels file during the process.

The question is what is wrong with my training process? and how I can extract my labels form graph on tensorboard ?

Comment: You might need to pass a different label vocabulary file to the inference program

Comment: @ِAlexandre Passos Could you please elaborate more, I'm new to machine learning field and my background is Architectural engineering

Comment: I mean the --output_labels= argument